# Vector construction from null space and column space

Tags: linear-algebra

We have that the system Ax=b don't have a solution (ex: in LS problem) A is a matrix MxN (M>N) with rank(A) = N. We know that the orthogonal complement of Range(A) is Null($A^T$). So the vector b can be reconstructed from the basis of column space of A and the basis of null space $A^T$? If it is possible, how can I prove this result?

For clarification of the question, consider:
[image]

The orthogonal complement of the column-space of A is the null space of $A^T$. So its possible to obtain the vector d by the basis of column space of A and null space of $A^T$? 
Thanks!

Comment: You can prove this using the properties of matrix multiplication and the orthogonal projection onto each of these spaces. Recall that the orthogonal projection onto a non-zero vector $x$ is $xx^T/x^Tx$ and that if $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal then $x^Ty=y^Tx=0$.

Comment: So the arbitrarily vector d can be constructed from the column space basis and null space of rows basis?

Comment: You'll need to find the basis for the spaces you're interested in which depends on the matrix. Try some small cases. I recommend doing the $2 \times 2$ case and the the $3 \times 3$ case since they're relatively easy and you can generalize from there. This lets you sketch the column space and it's orthogonal compliment as is done in the figure but the $2\times 2$ case is easier and I recommend you start there. After you've done these toy problems you'll probably be able to find the pattern and generalize.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thanks for the suggestion. But you think its possible to construct any vector d from a full rank matrix A (M>N)?

Comment: What happens when $M=3$ and $N=1$?

Comment: I see. So its not possible, thanks!

Comment: No problem. I find that when you're asking about the existence of something it's always best to first check the trivial cases, then the extreme cases. Sometimes you can find an easy counter-example this way and it saves a lot of work.